# Repeated reconnect for internet access

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, tp-link

Whenever I connect to my home WiFi network through my laptop it works for a certain time but then fails to access the internet from thereon. A workaround that I have found is to reconnect to the network whenever this happens. I have found that this happens only when I connect through my Laptop and doesn't happen when I connect through my mobile device. So right now I am pretty sure this issue is related to my laptop's Wifi device.

Wifi Hardware:
Output of `lsusb` shows

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

Laptop Brand : HP

P.S : This is an external wifi USB adapter if there is any doubt

Comment: are you using any bluetooth devices? this happens to me if I am using a bluetooth speaker

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Nope, I don't have any active bluetooth devices.